# Chaves no Array PHP

Tags: php, laravel, array-multidimensional

Estou com uma dúvida bem besta, consegui identificar o problema, porém não consegui resolver.. hahahaha

É o seguinte... 
Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array:7 [▼
  1 => array:5 [▶]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  10 => array:5 [▶]
  16 => array:5 [▶]
  22 => array:5 [▶]
  13 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Poderão perceber que a minha chave de cada array não é sequencial, ou seja, iniciar no 0 e ir até N. Estou usando para criar a chave o id dos meus registros que estão no banco... Até aqui está tudo certo e bonito!

O problema é que quando eu uso um FOREACH para percorrer os elementos e exiber os valores, como exemplo, "name" ele me retorna falando que o INDEX não existe... porém se eu usar um output vardump ou print_r está exibindo os valores. Eu fiz um teste percorrendo apenas 1 vez o foreach e ele exibiu corretamente o valor NAME o problema ocorre depois da Chave 2, acredito eu que seja por não estar na ordem de chaves, porém o problema é que da maneira que fiz eu consigo ter acesso mais fácil aos filhos de cada Array...

Para ter uma visão melhor estou colocando abaixo o Array completo:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Inicio
            [link] => #start
            [icon] => fa fa-tachometer
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [name] => Dashboard Eventos
                            [link] => index/Dashboard-Vendas
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [name] => Dashboard Monitor
                            [link] => index/Dashboard-Monitor
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Cadastros
            [link] => #clientes
            [icon] => fa fa-user
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Clientes
                            [link] => clientes/Clientes
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Empresa
            [link] => #empresas
            [icon] => fa fa-building
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Usuarios
                            [link] => empresas/Colaborador
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [name] => Equipes
                            [link] => empresas/Equipes
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [name] => Minhas Empresas
                            [link] => empresas/Empresas
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [name] => Veiculos Valores
                            [link] => empresas/Veiculos-Valor
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                            [name] => Departamentos
                            [link] => empresas/Departamentos
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Oportunidades
            [link] => #oportunidades
            [icon] => fa fa-thumbs-up
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [name] => Relatorios
                            [link] => oportunidades/Oportunidades
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [name] => Carregar Eventos
                            [link] => oportunidades/Upload-Eventos
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => Mesa de Credito
            [link] => #credito
            [icon] => fa fa-money
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [name] => Propostas
                            [link] => propostas/Propostas
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => Relatorios
                            [link] => credito/Relatorios
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => Pesquisa Satisfacao
            [link] => #pesquisas
            [icon] => fa fa-line-chart
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [name] => Pesquisas
                            [link] => pesquisas/Pesquisas
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [name] => Relatorios
                            [link] => pesquisas/Relatorios
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Minhas Campanhas
                            [link] => campanhas/Minhas-Campanhas
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => Relatorios
                            [link] => campanhas/Relatorios
                            [icon] => fa fa-caret-right
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Estou acessando o Array da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php foreach($menu as $m): ?>                  
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-file"><?php $m['name']; ?></a>                                 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Como você acessa o array no foreach?

Comment: @rray Adicionei no topico principal como que estou acessando o array no foreach..

Comment: Precisa fazer outro `foreach` na chave `children`

Comment: O foreach exibe corretamente na primeira vez, mas ao usar foreach mais uma vez o problema ocorre, seria isso?

Comment: tenta fazer o seguinte var_dump(array_column($menu , "name"));, vai te retornar todos os nomes em um array

Comment: Não, no momento nem no Children estou tentando acessar, quero exibir primeiro os valores "Inicio", "Cadadastros", "Empresas" e etc.. quando tento acessar o name tenho o retorno " Undefined index: name "

Comment: Para acessar os children eu sei que vou precisar fazer mais um foreach no valor $m['children'], mas o problema está sendo no valor base do array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelos seus comentários na pergunta, você disse:

> quando tento acessar o name tenho o retorno " Undefined index: name

Isso ocorre porque o array na posiãço [13] não tem o index name. Para corrigir isso, você pode colocar o seu `foreach` da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach($menu as $m): ?>                  
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-file"><?php echo (isset($m['name'])) ? $m['name'] : ''; ?></a>                                 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Dessa forma, seu código irá verificar se existe o index para imprimir, caso não exista, ele ignora e imprime vazio.

Comment: Putz David, que mancada a minha! Agora que fui ver que não tem isso, no caso era  pra ter, foi um erro de relacionamento no banco! Putz... obrigadão @David, salvou a patria!